# try to get current and next schedule by php

Tags: php, mysql

i make a php program

this programe show Schedules of channels

in the page of the channel i want to display the current program and the next one ,

in the table of the Schedules i insert the time of the program in cell called " when "

```
select when from Schedules where channel_id = 13
```

this is will display the time of all the programms in timestamp

i wanna to output only the current program , and the next one only

---

sorry for bad english language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have something to test this against, however this query will get all schedules for channel id 13 that are scheduled after or at $time, we order all such results in asc order by when and finally choose first two out of them (which will be the program at $time and the next after this one)

```
SELECT field1,field2,when FROM Schedules where channel_id = 13 AND 
when >= $time ORDER BY when ASC LIMIT 2
```

Fill in for field1, field2, and $time variable as required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `when` column is of `DATETIME` type:

```
( SELECT * FROM Schedules where channel_id = 13 AND when <= NOW() ORDER BY when DESC LIMIT 1 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM Schedules where channel_id = 13 AND when > NOW() ORDER BY when ASC LIMIT 1 )
```